# Crystal Reports Multiple Fields If Then Else

Tags: crystal-reports

```
if {field 1}>0 then "Monday"
else  if isnull({field 1}) then
    If {field 2}>0 then  "Wednesday"
    else if isnull({Wednesday}) then "Test"
```

The report is linked to a excel spreadsheet and sql table.  The sql table is the one where the data resides for the formula.

The only result I receive is Monday.  There are numbers in field 2.

Thank you in advance for the assistance.  First post please forgive if the format or location is incorrect.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

It is a long shot, but try this:

```
if not isnull({field 1}) and {field 1}>0 then "Monday" //only changed this line
else  if isnull({field 1}) then
    If {field 2}>0 then  "Wednesday"
    else if isnull({Wednesday}) then "Test"
```

Crystal does not like to face null stuff.